# lsmod lists only one single module, no other modules available to load, how do I proceed?

Tags: kernel-modules

The system debian wheezy, platform ci20, stock imagination kernel 3.0.8.

the output of lsmod lists only one module, pvrsrvkm, which is the "out of tree graphics driver" by imagination.

The problem is I need to load another module (xpad) but it is not found (FATAL: Module xpad not found, as far as I know it is a stock kernel module, widely available. Modprobe doesn't work either, and I mean I cant seem to be able to load any module with it at all, like there is no extra modules available.

The question is why there is no modules available, not just that particular one and how do I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give some details, please. What kernel are you using? What kernel related packages do you have installed? And most importantly, what kernel module are you trying to load? Presumably it is not actually called `xyz`. try `dpkg -S module_name` in the first instance. Does that give anything?

Comment: The module I am trying to load is xpad (supposed to be a built-in kernel driver bundled with most distributions), the output of uname -r is 3.0.8-123453-gb3bae40, the result of the suggested command dpkg -S xpad is dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *xpad*. About the kernel related packages I do not know what kind of packages might that be and I did not install any kernel related packages anyways.

Comment: I can assure you no modules are blacklisted, what kind of a madman would blacklist ALL modules?! Sorry if I am not giving you the information you need if I knew what information to be looking for I probably would not be asking this sort of a question. Thanks for your interest anyway.

Comment: I was able to `modprobe xpad` on my wheezy installation. Please add the output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-` to your question. My kernel is 3.2.0 - that's the default for wheezy on amd64 at least. You probably need a newer kernel.

Comment: I will include that output asap. Architecture of the processor is mips and the kernel is supplied by imagination with their debian flashable image. As far as I can tell this module is not the only one missing, no modules is available, I mean at all. Modprobe does not seem to be aware of any modules and that is what confuses me the most. Ps. I will have what you asked for in half an hour or so.

Comment: Your setup may be non-standard. Perhaps the modules are in a separate package, or maybe (unlikely) they are compiled into the kernel.

Comment: Are there any module files (files with the `.ko` suffix) under `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel` ? (For example, `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.ko`).  Is your xpad module listed in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin` or `modules.alias` ?

Comment: The output of dpkg -l | grep linux- is: ii linux-libc-dev:mipsel 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 mipsel Linux support headers for userspace development

Comment: No input section under (..)/kernel/drivers, all there is media, pvrsrvkm.ko, scsi, usb. Looked in those but no xpad.ko anywhere in there. Xpad is not found in modules.builtin nor modules.alias

Comment: If your distro doesn't include some drivers due to space limitations, you can conceivably compile from source. https://github.com/MIPS/CI20_linux/blob/ci20-v3.0.8/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.c

Comment: Certainly very helpful, thank you. If you dont mind me asking, it is not there because support for it was not included at the kernels compile time, right?/

Comment: My guess is that, in order to keep the filesystem image size down (according to http://www.elinux.org/CI20_Distros, it's around 1GB), a number of packages and a number of kernel modules were not built.

Comment: It's clear from your description that you're running a custom variant of Debian, where at least the kernel package has been modified to include a different kernel version and a vastly reduced set of drivers. Please post the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`, of all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` if any, and the output of apt-cache policy 'linux-(image|headers)-.*'`.

Answer (score 0):

There's so little detail here at the moment so we're just taking a stab in the dark at the moment.

Reason why there could be only one kernel module present is that it's the only one needed, most driver requirements have been compiled as into the kernel not as loadable kernel modules,  loading of many kernel modules have been blacklisted (for various reasons. I've used this technique to avoid instability issues with some drivers, conflicts with others, and so on...), or your system has been compromised (explains the funny business all round. There could be deleted files anywhere/everywhere...).

Possibilities as to why module isn't found include it hasn't been compiled (but that doesn't sound right as you seem to be using a stock kernel which should mean that there are many modules available), your system has been compromised (explains the funny business all round. There could be deleted files anywhere/everywhere...), or it hasn't been installed (assuming that it is not a core kernel module and is from a third party).

Comment: All I can add is that I did not modify the system too much since I got it, I would not know how to anyway, I am just confused since there is no available modules AT ALL so I wonder why would it be and how to proceed in such a case. thanks anyhow.

Comment: Maybe I mislead you. When I say 'stock imagination kernel' I mean it is imagination's kernel so it differs a fair bit from the stock debian kernel. That seems to be an issue anyway in this case, modules are not there since they were not included at the kernel's compile time. Other than than that good tips, thank you.